# Upload photos and video in AWS documentdb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have a challenge to upload photo or video in AWS documentdb as part of their capabilities to handle profiles, CMS, etc. But I've been not able to find an example.. Can you share an example if you already went thru the same use case?

Comment: I am not clear about your use case. From what i think, you want to upload digital assets from an app to AWS. To store assets like images/videos, you would typically store them in S3 and metadata into a database. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: US upload photos in AWS documentdb, this because https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/   (Store and query content management data). And agree I was thinking on S3, but AWS documentdb says this is possible.

Comment: Never heard of that storing binary data. Typically will hold metadata and S3 stores binary data.